# Interaction between remote sql database and iphone app

Tags: sql, ios

I got a sql database host by a server and I need both access to the data and write some data. My question is what is the best way to do this ? I would be ready to drop the sql if you guys think there is a better way (even if I though it's the best way, knowing that a lot of user could have access to the data at the same time).

Well, I need some advices.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create API (application programming interface) on you server to interact with your data. The simplest will be the one which works over http.
This way you could also manage access for each user.

For example:
Server with php and [cfpropertylist](http://code.google.com/p/cfpropertylist/) library installed.

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'lists') {
    // connect to database and fetch data
    // transform it to properly list using cfpropertylist library and print it
}
```

On iPhone install [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library.
It will simplify the process of making requests to server.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server?action=lists"];
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    id structure = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:responseData
                                                    mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                                                              format:NULL 
                                                    errorDescription:nil];
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you be a little more specific please ? And may be give a simple example ? Cheers

Comment: Hey @Bob, I added a brief example.

Comment: Thx. I finally used ASIHTTPRequest classes, use post to transmit data to the server and use an intermediate xml file for getting data from the server. It works great !

Answer (score 0):

Never do a sql <--> app-connection, as it's bound to leave your system vulnerable - instead use some type of web-language (such as `php`, `asp` or `jsp`) to control the communication between the elements.

It would result in the app talking to the website, which actually forwards the essential parts to the database, and then returns the needed data without giving out the database credentials for everyone to share.

Comment: Well yes, but I don't really see the thing ! Using php, how could I transfer data to my app (I'm not that good in web development, I hate that!). And what about writing data ? Transmit them by a post from the iApp ?

Comment: You can transfer the `jsonencode`d data from `PHP/MySQL` using `JSON` (http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) in `Objective-C`, and send it back to `PHP` via a regular `POST`-request.